Laravel Route not hitting Controller (Laravel Breeze)
I've been trying to migrate an old project of mine to Laravel, handling the authentication through Laravel Breeze.
In one file I've got two post forms for logging in and registering.
The login one is the one that I can't get to work:
<div class="login">
    <span>Welcome Back!</span>
    <h2 class="title">
        Sign In
    </h2>
    <form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="POST" id="loginform">
        @csrf
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="Username" name="login_username" id="login_username">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password" name="login_password" id="login_password">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn" name="Login_Button">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p class="existing-account" onclick="move('toRegister')">Not yet registered?</p>
</div>

Routes are set up like this:
Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
    ->name('login');

Route::post('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);

And finally in the AuthenticatedSessionController I've got this:
public function store(LoginRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    dd($request);
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect(route('home'));
}

But for some reason I don't get the datadump neither the redirect. I stay on the same page where I have my forms. I honestly don't know where to start since the routes seems correct.

For route with post add name like ->name('login.store') then change action="{{ route('login') }}" to action="{{ route('login.store') }}"

This made no difference sadly

In such situation you should always check

whether the request was actually sent
whether it was a POST request like you expected
what the response status was (if it's a 500, then you have an error and you will need to look into the server logs)
what the response was

In our current case
return redirect(route('home'));

requires Helper to be used. Make sure all syntax errors you might have are sorted out as well as all resources you use have their namespace also in use at the code location of their use.
It's very likely that you simply have an error that you can check in the server logs and which contains a message which tells you what the error was as well as a stack-trace of the location where the error occurred.

Request was sent with the response code 302. No errors in the log.

@SBECK1 302 means that the location has temporarily moved. Which means you have not been targeting the correct route. Can you tell me what is the exact URL that your request targeted?

You mean the request url? 127.0.0.1:8000/login, but as I created the route "home" as 127.0.0.1:8000/, this shouldn't happen when it's properly redirected, right?
